# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am new to those technologies. 
My OS is ubuntu-18.04 and using anaconda to create a virtual environment with pip installation with all necessary package. I also install Chrome and chromedriver with the same version to run the selenium. I also create a test.service under /etc/systemd/system

I cann't post image in stackoverflow.
The problem can be seen in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI66P.png) with command (`sudo systemctl status test`)

> gunicorn[25770]:   File "/home/anaconda/port8788/hct/hct_information.py", line 21, in testDriver 
> gunicorn[25770]:     driver.get(url) 
> gunicorn[25770]:   File "/home/chaoyang/anaconda3/envs/selenium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get 
> gunicorn[25770]:     self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url}) 
> gunicorn[25770]:   File "/home/chaoyang/anaconda3/envs/selenium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute 
> gunicorn[25770]:     self.error_handler.check_response(response) 
> gunicorn[25770]:   File "/home/chaoyang/anaconda3/envs/selenium/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response 
> gunicorn[25770]:     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> gunicorn[25770]: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
> gunicorn[25770]:   (Session info: headless chrome=86.0.4240.183)

My Flask Code is below:

```
import flask
from flask import request
import argparse
from hct import hct_information as hct

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return hct.testDriver('https://www.google.com/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

My selenium Code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

def testDriver(url):
options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') #for linux avoid chrome not started
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"')
#options.add_argument('window-size=500*250')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=('/usr/bin/chromedriver'), options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

title = driver.title
driver.close()
return title
```

It should be a simple program. Unfortunately, when I test separately using python to run the flask api everything is fine, even with `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 test:app` is also run without above message.
Any Idea where I done things incorrectly????

Answer (score 8):

I've got a similar case and found out that the problem, in my case, was due to using the option of headless web.

Try commenting that line in your code and see if the error is gone.

I am still investigation how to have the app run without displaying the web and not getting the error.

Comment: have you found a way to run without displaying the web and not getting the error?

Comment: Is there any possibility to use it with headless displaying?

Comment: The “ERR_CONNECTION_RESET” error code is particular to Google Chrome. However, you may encounter similar messages in other browsers. For example, Firefox returns a “The connection was reset” error code.

Connection reset errors appear when you visit a website, and the browser fails to establish a connection. When that happens, the connection is “reset,” which means the server cannot transmit data to your browser.