# Why does Selenium headless browser using Chrome cause unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to figure out why I can't load [this website](https://appft.uspto.gov/) using Selenium + Chrome without catching the error (Other websites load normally)

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET (Session info: headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)` .

When I run the program without the `--headless` argument it works fine. The error occurs no matter how I implement the headless aspect of the browser. for example `options.headless=True, options.add_argument("--headless")` both produce the same error. I've noticed other people have had [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814682/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-neterr) which is how I learned that turning off --headless identified the source of the issue.

This seems to be an issue with Chromedriver because I was able to load the webpage with the Firefox headless browser and GeckoDriver.

To make sure it wasn't an issue related to the Chromedriver version I installed ChromedriverManager.

I tried adding in sleep functions at various points in case adding wait times mimicked the opening of the browser etc. which didn't produce any different results. Firefox headless browser solved it technically but pythonanywhere doesn't support it anymore so I can't put it online.

full output below. Thanks

Here is the code to run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.headless = True
website = 'https://appft.uspto.gov/'
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=s)

driver.get(website)
```

and here is the output

```
 ====== WebDriver manager ======
    Current google-chrome version is 97.0.4692
    Get LATEST chromedriver version for 97.0.4692 google-chrome
    Driver [C:\Users\Compuester\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\97.0.4692.71\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Compuester/PycharmProjects/selenium/testes.py", line 13, in <module>
        driver.get(website)
      File "C:\Users\Compuester\anaconda3\envs\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 436, in get
        self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
      File "C:\Users\Compuester\anaconda3\envs\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\Compuester\anaconda3\envs\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
      (Session info: headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)
    Stacktrace:
    Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00ADFDC3+2555331]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A777F1+2127857]
        Ordinal0 [0x00972E08+1060360]
        Ordinal0 [0x0096F9B1+1046961]
        Ordinal0 [0x009659BD+1006013]
        Ordinal0 [0x009665D0+1009104]
        Ordinal0 [0x00965C1E+1006622]
        Ordinal0 [0x0096527D+1004157]
        Ordinal0 [0x009643FA+1000442]
        Ordinal0 [0x009646B6+1001142]
        Ordinal0 [0x009743FA+1065978]
        Ordinal0 [0x009C7BAD+1407917]
        Ordinal0 [0x009B7B0C+1342220]
        Ordinal0 [0x009C75FA+1406458]
        Ordinal0 [0x009B7976+1341814]
        Ordinal0 [0x009936B6+1193654]
        Ordinal0 [0x00994546+1197382]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00C79622+1619522]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D2882C+2336844]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B723E1+541697]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B71443+537699]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A7D18E+2150798]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A81518+2168088]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A81660+2168416]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A8B330+2208560]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75C7FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77947A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77947A6E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Curious did you ever solve this? I'm running into very similar on https://tmsearch.uspto.gov/

Comment: I don't remember to be honest. I have a feeling we were being blocked, from the link you provided -"TESS is intended for use by the general public. TESS is not intended to be a source for bulk downloads of USPTO data. ... Individuals, companies, IP addresses, or blocks of IP addresses who, in effect, deny service to the general public by generating unusually high numbers of daily TESS accesses (searches, pages, or hits), whether generated manually or in an automated fashion, may be denied access to these servers without notice"  I think a new agent with new IP, details may temp fix it

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue in `s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Please use follow code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver    
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    
    
    chrome_options = Options()    
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options = chrome_options)
    link = "your site url"
    dirver.get(link)
```

Comment: Hey Victor, I still received the same error but thanks for your effort!